# get touch event coordinates relative to the parent

Tags: android

I have a linear layout that has an image in it
I am trying to get the touch event coordinates of the image relative to the parent that contains it.
Do you know I can  I get these? getX and getY are returning position relative to self

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The **MotionEvent** class has methods **getX()** to get X touch point corresponding to that view and **getRawX()** to get X touch point corresponding to screen.

So to get X touch point corresponding to parent you can get that by a simple calculation:

```
     view.getLeft() + motionEvent.getX()
```

The **getLeft()** returns Left position of this view relative to its parent

Comment: Thank you. for the extended info so I guess I shall accept as the correct answer since it has more explanation of whats going on .Thank you

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    System.out.println((v.getLeft() + event.getX()) + "," + (v.getTop() + event.getY()));
    return false;
}
```